# What is the biggest military aircraft?

Tags: military

I was just informed that the world's biggest aircraft was the Antonov An-225, and huge airplane.

That being said, I was curious what the world's biggest military aircraft was. Are there limitations such as maximum speed etc,.?

Comment: Biggest payload, gross takeoff weight, wingspan, length, etc, or some combination of those?

Comment: Also current military, ex-military converted to civilian use (the An-225) or historic (perhaps the Hughs "Spruce Goose").  And by wingspan, the Stratolaunch carrier aircraft is the largest flying plane.

Comment: Actually, I think the military zeppelins were way way larger than any airplanes of all time.

Answer (score 2):

Because the AN-225 is not a military aircraft and Zeppelin will be winner, there is no one biggest **plane**.

- C5 Galaxy = **76 meters long**, 68 m wingspan, 20 m high, wing area:576 m2
- An-124 = 69 meters long, **73 m wingspan**, 21 m high, wing area: 628 m2
- (Bonus:) Hughes H-4 Hercules (Spruce Goose on picture) = 66.55 meters long, **97,54 wingspan, 24 m high, wing area: 1 061,8 m2**

See this : [image: comparison]

Source:https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules#/media/Fichier%3AGiant_planes_comparison.svg

Comment: Not quite sure why this got a down vote. It seems to accurately point out that "biggest" depends on what dimension one measures... Except, of course, that it's trying to answer an unclear question.

Comment: ... and then there's the issue of volume, which some would also consider a measure of "big".

Comment: @Michael Tracy: And also gross weight, or cargo capacity.